# Get value change event on drop to input element

Tags: javascript, html, input, drag-and-drop, dom-events

In cross-browser Javascript, how to get an event after the value of an `<input>` element is changed because of a text being dragged and dropped into the field?

```
input.addEventListener("change", cb); // Is not triggered on drop
input.addEventListener("drop", cb);   // Is triggered before the value change
```

A snippet to demonstrate the problem:

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let button = document.getElementById('button');
let div = document.getElementById('div');

function log(msg) {
 let el = document.createElement('pre');
 el.textContent = msg;
 div.appendChild(el);
}

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
 log("CHANGE: " + input.value);
});

input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
 log("KEYUP: " + input.value);
});

input.addEventListener("drop", function() {
 log("DROP: " + input.value);
});

button.addEventListener("click", function()  {
 log("CLICK: " + input.value);
});

log("Try dragging text into the input field");
```

```html
<input id="input"></input>
<button id="button">Click</button>
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: I found one workaround that at least works in Chrome: to trigger a `setTimeout(cb, 0)` on *drop* before reading value.

Comment: I tried your workaround using setTimeout and it is also working in firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text value of the dropped data with the [getData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData) method:

```
// This will get the current data value dropped as a string
event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
```

and prevent this same value to be set in the input with:

```
// This will prevent the input to be changed with the dropped data
event.preventDefault();
```

So the full event handler would be like this:

```
input.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var textData = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    // do whatever you want with the the text data
});
```

So instead of trying to get the input value at the right moment, you can intercept the data from the drop event and do stuff with it. You could even set it as text later.

Let me know if it solves your problem.